How can Hertzian mechanics possibly give different solutions for static and dynamic particle contact?
I am trying to understand a case of impact between a sphere and a half-space.

Suppose I have a particle resting on the half-space in the gravity. The penetration depth $\delta_{max}$ of resting particle can be obtained from force balance of $$F_g=F_{Hertz},$$
where $F_g=m_pg$, $F_{Hertz}=k\delta_{max}^{3/2}$, here $k=4/3E^{*}R^{1/2}$ which is constant, $m_p$ is mass of particle, $g$ is acceleration due to gravity, $E^{*}$ is effective elastic modulus, and $R$ is effective radius of half-space.
Solving the force balance for penetration depth $\delta$ yields
$$ \delta_{max}^{3/2}=\frac{m_pg}{k} \tag{1}$$

Now, let's assume that the particle had some initial normal velocity $v$. Therefore, kinetic energy $E_{kin}$ and try to calculate penetration depth. In this case, I am not sure if we can make a balance of forces. I found a more common approach, which is to transform forces into work by integration $W= \int F \ d  \delta $. If the contact is fully elastic and no energy is lost, the whole kinetic energy of impact needs to be counteracted by the work done by contact force. Therfore we can formulate energy balance
$$ E_{kin} = \int_0^{\delta_{max}} F \ d  \delta  $$ for now ignore gravity and solve only for contact forces so $F=F_{Hertz}$ thus
$$ E_{kin} = \int_0^{\delta_{max}} k\delta^{3/2} \ d  \delta  $$
this yields
$$ E_{kin}= [\frac{2}{5} k\delta^{5/2} + C]_0^{\delta_{max}}$$
integration constant $C$ vanishes and we get solution


$$ \delta_{max}^{5/2}= \frac{E_{kin}}{k} \frac{5}{2} $$

my problem starts when we assume that gravity plays a role, i.e., in the case when normal impact velocity is small; thus, $E_{kin}$ is small, and the contact is dominated by gravitational force. Using the same approach as in the second case and assuming that gravity acts in the opposite direction from contact force. I get an energy balance
$$ E_{kin}=\int_0^{\delta_{max}} k\delta^{3/2} - m_pg \ d  \delta  $$
the integration result is
$$ E_{kin}= [\frac{2}{5} k\delta^{5/2}- m_pg \delta + C]_0^{\delta_{max}}$$
integration constant $C$ vanishes and we get solution
$$ E_{kin}= \frac{2}{5} k\delta_{max}^{5/2}- m_pg \delta_{max}$$
I found it strange that if we assume that $\lim_{E_{kin} \to 0}$ and rearrange above equation we get
$$\frac{2}{5} k\delta_{max}^{5/2}= m_pg \delta_{max} $$
simplifying for $\delta_{max}$ gives
$$ \delta_{max}^{3/2}= \frac{m_pg}{k} \frac{5}{2} \tag{2}$$
Now, when I compare the results from equations $1$ and $2$, which I expect to be identical, I find that I am off by a factor of 5/2.

This discrepancy is puzzling, and I would appreciate any insights into what I might be missing.
Edit: I realized that I should refine my question. The inconsistency arises from the integration process. If I choose not to integrate force but instead convert kinetic energy to force, I assume that when $E_{kin}$ is zero, the converted force $\frac{d \ E_{kin}}{d \delta}$ would also approach zero, thus preventing the inconsistency. My question is: why can't I integrate the force and create an energy balance for the system?

I am not 100% sure I understand the question. But reading through points 1 and 2, it sounds like you can reframe your question in terms of a mass on a spring. Situation 1 seems to be analogous to hanging a mass on a spring in a gravitational field, and asking how the equilibrium displacement of the spring in gravity shifts relative to the usual equilibrium displacement of the spring. Situation 2 sounds like you have given the spring an initial impulse, and integrate the kinetic energy until the spring comes to rest. If you agree with this analogy, then there is a big difference between (...)

(...) situations 1 and 2, since situation 1 occurs in equilibrium, while when the mass comes to rest in situation 2, the net force on it is not zero -- the spring is compressed and will begin to accelerate the mass back toward equilibrium. So, it may not be surprising that you find results based on situations 1 and 2 are inconsistent. Apologies if this analogy is not helpful for your question.

I agree with @Andrew; this looks like the factor-of-two problem when considering energy vs. work when a restoring force is present, with the additional nuance that the restoring force is nonlinear (because the contact area is a function of displacement). Scenario (1) considers a particle at rest in an indentation formed by its weight. Scenario (3) considers a particle set on a smooth surface and allowed to indent the half-space below it. It will overshoot and rebound; when it stabilizes, some energy will have been lost to frictional heating.

If this resolves the issue satisfactorily for you, one of us can expand these comments into an answer.

Thank you very much for the feedback. Your analogy is helpful. To reframe it with springs:
In one scenario, I have an unloaded spring to which I suddenly apply a gravitational field, aiming to determine the spring's maximum displacement (case 1). In another scenario, I give an initial impulse to the spring and calculate its maximum displacement (case 2).
However, my issue arises when I use the equations for case 2 but assume the initial impulse is infinitesimally small (case 3). This case should be almost identical to case 1, yet the solution differs by a factor of 5/2.

I used the second case to introduce the equations for case 3 so the reasoning for the shift from force balance to energy balance is clear. You might be correct that it is a factor-of-two problem. I was unaware of this issue before. From a quick read on this problem, it seems that the factor of two is related to the integration of force. Could you please expand on this answer?

I realized my first analogy was incorrect. In the first case, I am trying to find a displacement that is in equilibrium, not the maximum displacement.
